# AS3 AIR: How to remove html elements in HTMLLoader before render?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, air

I'm making a custom webbrower by Adobe Air.

I would like to add a html filter function that disable javascript & iframe.

If I can get html code before render, I would delete tag elements with regexp.

I guess I can something with htmlloader when htmlloader's LocationChangeEvent dispatch.

Comment: So, like, what did you try? Did you search for something? Do you have a specific Problem? Any code? It's not easy to answer your question without any details.

Answer (score 3):

Kim, you can get to the HTML using something like this:

`myHtmlLoader.window.document.childNodes[0].innerHTML`

but you need to make sure you don't access it until the document in loaded (see above) otherwise it will be null.

When I use the above code while loading a simple file, I see this:

`<body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">hello world</body>`

If you can't get it to work with the above, let me know and I'll try to drum up some sample code.

Comment: Kim, did this work for you or do you need some sample code?  If it worked, please accept this answer and close the question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch [Event.HTML_DOM_INITIALIZE](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/html/HTMLLoader.html#event%3ahtmlDOMInitialize) on loader. On this moment, html is loaded, DOM tree created, scripts not yet launched. Then you can get `window` object from loader and modify its children hierarchy (note that this is not deleting tags with regexp.)
You can also get loaded html, parse it as a text, apply filter and set filtered text to html again, but then you'll get another HTML_DOM_INITIALIZE event and risk of damaged html. The choice is yours, of course.

Comment: What property I modify? There's so many property in htmlLoader.widow. I tried and failed. 'htmlLoader.window.HTMLIFRAMEElement = null' didn't work. At dom init event, document.getElement method return nothing. (getElementById, TagName works correctly after complete event dispatched). Please help me more... Thanks.

Comment: You need domWindow.document object. It has childNodes property, where all html elements are stored.

Comment: window.document.childNodes.item() return null only when "html_dom_initialize" event dispatch. It return html elements(include innerHTML) after "complete" event dispatched. I want a iframe filter. So I should remove iframe element(or delete it on htmlcontent string) before "complete" event dispatch. I spend a couble of days to solve this. But I can't find a solution. :( Anyway thanks for answer.

Comment: There is also `htmlText` property to mess with. If you change text and set it again, you'll get another set of events (and content will have different origin from original site.)

Comment: You mean flex's html.htmlText? If so, it also return null. I can't find htmlText property in htmlLoader or window.document object.

Comment: It seems htmlText can be unavailable because of Flash security (untrusted content.) But on `complete` event I can see html.domWindow.document.childNodes[1] - it is node of type HTML and it contains children HEAD and BODY.

Comment: um. That's right. On Complete event, I can get complete document. html element, htmltext, innerhtml, etc... But for javascript/iframe block function, I can't use complete event. Because javascript/iframe code excute before complete event. So I should modify html code on dom_init event. At first, I thought I could make it by overriing htmlloader's load & loadstring method. But it's not.    Thanks.